# is there a way of configuring the level of jersey client request logging?

Tags: java, logging, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using `jersey client` 2.25 and I am logging my requests. I'd like an easy way to switch this logging on and off, preferably through a logging configuration file. I've tried putting a `logging.properties` files in the class path but this does not seem to have any effect.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("my logger");

LoggingFilter filter = new LoggingFilter(logger, true);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(filter);
```

Note: that the `LoggingFilter` is deprecated for this version but appears to come back in 2.5.1. The advice for 2.25 is to use `LoggingFeature` but I note that this is not present at all in 2.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you are not able to find `LoggingFeature` in `jersey 2.25.1` version.

Below is one way of doing it using `LoggingFeature` -

**Client Class -**

Create your client object and set logging level to `Fine` -

```
// Define it as a constant
Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(YourClient.class.getName());

// Set logging level to FINE level for request/response logging    
Feature feature = new LoggingFeature(LOGGER, Level.FINE, Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY,
                LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(feature).build();
```

**log_config.properties file -**

Suppose below is the log configuration file -

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler

# Using this level, request/response logging can be controlled
.level= FINE

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ./logs/application.log

java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 5000

java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 50

java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

**Main Class -**

Use this log configuration file in your client application -

```
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("./config/log_config.properties"));
```

Now, your `loggingfeature` is configured to log data at `FINE` level and your log configuration file is also configured for `FINE` level logging, it means request/response will be logged in logs.

If you change level in log configuration file, suppose from `FINE` to `INFO`, your request/response will no longer be logged in logs.

**Edit** Following are the maven dependencies which I am using -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependency for JSON request/response handling in Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Edit** For console logging, you just need below configuration for printing request/response at `FINE` level -

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= FINE

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

**Import Statement of Required Classes -**

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature.Verbosity;
```

Comment: Are you able to post your pom or gradle build file, or just a list of your dependencies. I don't have LoggingFeature in my dependencies.

Comment: Ah, you were talking about 2.25.1 not 2.5.1 - and I was confused about release ordering! Got it, thanks.

Comment: @natk FYI, There is no 2.5.1 version of jersey released yet. Also, if this answer solved your question, then, accept this answer.

Comment: Actually this is not working for me. I get the logs, and am able to configure the level with the logging.properties file if I use a LoggingFilter. When I switch to the LoggingFeature, I do not get the logs.

Comment: @natk It is strange. Are you using same log properties file that I pasted above ? Can u show your log properties file, code snippet ?

Comment: I am loggin to the console. This is my properties file.
`handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`

`.level=FINE`

`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO`
`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`

`org.glassfish.jersey.client=FINER`
`org.glassfish.jersey.client.handler=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler`

Comment: @natk I edited my answer with required console log configuration. The configuration you pasted, in that configuration, mainly you need to change `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` to `FINE` so that `FINE` level logs will print. Value of both `.level` and `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` should be same

Comment: guys can you please add the imports for `Feature feature = new LoggingFeature(LOGGER, Level.FINE, Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY,
                LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE);` ?

Comment: @MHosafy I updated answer with the `import statements` as per `jersey 2.25.1` version. Not sure about the latest version.